# popultaing listview with mp3 files from phone

Tags: windows, xaml, listview, uwp, audio-player

I am tryng to develop a UWP Music App using `MediaElement`. Previously I had used `OpenPicker` to select one music file at a time from local storage. But now I wants to make a `ListView` which can scan the whole phone for music file and will populate the listview with them. Anyone can help regarding this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. so, please update an answer with your existing code and we help you solve the problem

Comment: i don't have code right now. I don't even know where to start. I am new UWP. I jst knw about implementing `ListView` and `MediaElement`

Comment: @Ravi 1) Figure out how to list the found MP3 files in a listview. Start with a statically initialized dummy list of files so you're only wrestling with one problem at a time. Come here for help if you run into any specific snags that you can't get around by googling 2) Figure out how to list the actual mp3 files on the phone, and start using that instead of the dummy list. Again, if you run into any specific concrete problems, you could come here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP applications have a limited access to the host device file system.
You can easily access the user music library which is probably what you want.

The music library folder is available from the [KnowFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br227151(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.storage.knownfolders)%3Bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3Dv5.0)%3Bk(devlang-csharp)&rd=true) API. It will allow you to access the [KnowFolders.MusicLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.knownfolders.musiclibrary.aspx) folder. You can then get the files' list using [StorageFolder.CreateFileQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br227255.aspx)

```
var query    = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileQuery();
var allFiles = await query.GetFilesAsync();

foreach(var f in allFiles)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(f.DisplayName);
}
```

Beware that access to the user folder is retricted. You will have to declare the "music library" capability in your application manifest

```
 <Capabilities>
    <uap:Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
</Capabilities>
```